# Getting NSException while filling UICollectionView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, clgeocoder

In my code I'm calling the `Apple` geocoder:

```
private func callGoogleReverseGeocodingWebservice(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)
    self.defaults.synchronize()
    if (!self.alreadyShowedHashtagSuggestionPanel && defaults.object(forKey: "doNotShowHashtags") == nil) {
        self.alreadyShowedHashtagSuggestionPanel = true
    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { placemarks, error in
        guard let addressDict = placemarks?[0].addressDictionary else {
            return
        }
        self.suggestedHashtags.removeAllObjects()

        if let street = addressDict["Thoroughfare"] as? String {
            self.suggestedHashtags.add(street)
        }
        if let city = addressDict["City"] as? String {
            self.suggestedHashtags.add(city)
        }
        if let country = addressDict["Country"] as? String {
            self.suggestedHashtags.add(country)
        }

        if(self.suggestedHashtags.count > 0) {
            print(self.suggestedHashtags.count)
            print("here")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.hashtagsCollectionView.reloadData()
            } 
        } else {
            print("there's nothing here")
        }

    })
    }
}
```

Every result from the method above is placed in an array, and that array is used in method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    print("cellForRow")
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "hashtagCell", for: indexPath) as! HashtagCollectionViewCell

    let hashtagName:String =  self.suggestedHashtags[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item] as! String
    cell.hashtagName.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    cell.hashtagName.font = font
    cell.hashtagName.text = hashtagName
    print("this is \(hashtagName)")
    return cell 
}
```

Unfortunately, sometimes this line:

```
let hashtagName:String =  self.suggestedHashtags[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item] as! String
```

throws error that says:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I'm not sure what might be causing this issue, from what I've read it seems like the geocoder avoids allowing too much requests, so I think that after querying it too much - it returns empty data, therefore `as! String` throws error - but it's just my random thoughts, maybe there's something else that I might be missing?

Comment: Post the full exception message.  If you have an exception breakpoint you may need to remove/step past it so that the full message gets logged in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't cast `IndexPath` to `NSIndexPath`, it may cause this kind of problem. 
So please try to change this line

```
let hashtagName:String = self.suggestedHashtags[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item] as! String
```

To

```
let hashtagName = (self.suggestedHashtags[indexPath.item] as? String) ?? ""
```

Hope this will help to you